# How to retain value in second activity after re-clicking the button from MainActivity to launch the second activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have 2 activities. First is `MainActivity` and second is `SecondActivity`.

`MainActivity` has a `textView` and `button`called "Launch". Using `intent` and startActivityForResult I am passing a list to `SecondActivity`.

`SecondActivity` has a `spinner` and 2 `buttons`;a select `button` and a `cancel` button.

On selection of an item from the `spinner`, when user clicks on `Select` button, the option chosen in the `spinner` is populated in the `textView` of `MainActivity`.

Now when the user again clicks on "Launch", `SecondActivity` launches however, the `spinner` doesn't hold the value the user had chosen last time, instead it shows the first value of the `spinner`.

Is their anyway, how I can retain the value selected in the `SecondActivity` chosen by the user in it's previous use.

Comment: yes, save the index of the spinner somewhere somewhere - a database, shared prefs, a static variable, quite a few options available

Comment: Thanks for answering, below it has been elaborated, so will try and answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the SecondActivity, you should return the select item of spinner to MainActivity. If it is MainActiviy can get that value in this function :

```
        onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  @Nullable Intent data)
```

before that, you shold show SecondActivity with

```
       startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_CODE);
```

so the code can be like this

```
        private static SECOND_CODE = 1001;

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_CODE);
                

         @Override
         protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  @Nullable Intent data) {
              super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
              if (requestCode == SECOND_CODE && resultCode == 
                    Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                 // you can get selected spinner item here
              }
          }
```

After that, when you want to show SecondActivity again

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.thisSecondActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra("selected_spinner", /*the spinner item you got from above function*/)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SECOND_CODE);
```

and in SecondActivity, you can get the selected spinner item from getIntent()

```
        String selected_spinner = getIntent().getStringExtra("selected_spinner");
```

Then you can find this string in Spinner and select it.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this worked great dude! However since I have several buttons and I am using same function to open `activities` for each button so, I removed `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` as this was causing crashes. Rest was a charm. I just thought there would be a way to keep session data held for second activity, but re capturing selected data was pretty obvious but your code made it super easy! Thanks!

Comment: you should add this code :             
               intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Removing this can cause crashes for over Android version 9

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting crashes if I add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`. That's when I removed it and my desired output was coming. Any explanations why?

Answer (score 0):

You can persist information using SharedPreferences, just store the last selection from the user and then retrieve it to set on SecondActivity.

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString("myPreferences"), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//Store a value
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("selection","foo");

//Get the value
String selection = prefs.getString("selection", "defaultOption");
```

Here is the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.